# How to list multiple pieces of data from data table using a variable

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I wrote the below program to send HTML Email to the demo users in this table:

[image]

I want to send only one email and lists all of the information for each customer. Currently, if a customer has 10 books past due, then the customer will get 10 emails based on the table structure, because each book loan is a separate record.

**For example:**

Dear Jim Carey:
The following book(s) are due:

1. How to Fix Cars
2. James Bond Returns

Is there a way that I can send only one email for each customer but list each item in the email. For example list all the books due?

Fox example: Sending an email using the above table, Jim Carey will get 2 emails, instead of 1. I would like to send just one but list both the books due.

```
class Program
{
static DataSet dtProfile = Database.AcquireData();
static DataTable table = dtProfile.Tables[0];

static string CustFName;
static string CustLName;
static string CheckoutDate;
static string DueDate;
static string BookName;

public static void SendEmail()
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
     CustFName = row["CustFName"].ToString();
     CustLName = row["CustLName"].ToString();
     CheckoutDate = row["CheckoutDate"].ToString();
     DueDate = row["DueDate"].ToString();
     BookName = row["BookName"].ToString();          
     string body = PopulateBody(CustFName, CustLName, CheckoutDate, DueDate, BookName);<br />
     SendHtmlFormattedEmail("Email", "Subject", body);
    }
}

public static string PopulateBody(string custFName, string custLName,
    string checkoutDate, string dueDate, string bookName)
{
    string body = string.Empty;

    using (StreamReader reader = 
        new StreamReader(Path.GetFullPath(@"Z:\folder\email.html")))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    body = body.Replace("{#First Name#}", custFName);
    body = body.Replace("{#Last Name#}",  custLName);
    body = body.Replace("{#Checkout Date#}", checkoutDate);
    body = body.Replace("{#Due Date#}",  dueDate);
    body = body.Replace("{#Book Name#}", bookName);

    return body;
}

public static void SendHtmlFormattedEmail(string recepientEmail, string subject, string body)
{
    using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
    {
      mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"]);
      mailMessage.Subject = subject;
      mailMessage.Body = body;
      mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
      mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recepientEmail));
      SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
      smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
      smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]);
      System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
      NetworkCred.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
      NetworkCred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
      smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
      smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
      smtp.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
      smtp.Send(mailMessage);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SendEmail();
}

}
```

Comment: In the for each instead of doing a SEND EMAIL
Take a string and keep adding up the list of books. then call the send email after you have generated the book list the person has outstanding.

Comment: Ok looking at your code, that may not work.... hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a collection of email data for each email address.  Then iterate over the individual addresses and send out the emails.

```
class Program
{
    static DataSet dtProfile = null; //Database.AcquireData();
    static DataTable table = dtProfile.Tables[0];

    public static void SendEmail()
    {
        // Create the dictionary to hold the email data for each individual email. This allows us 
        // to group all of the books due for an individual together.  We will use the email address
        // as the key for the dictionary instead of CustomerID in case the user has given us two
        // different email addresses.
        Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> emailList = new Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>>();

        // Iterate over the dataset and populate the dictionary
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            // grab the email address, will be the key for the dictionary
            string email = row["Email"].ToString();

            // if we haven't processed a row for this email yet, initialize the entry for it
            if (!emailList.ContainsKey(email))
            {
                emailList.Add(email, new List<DataRow>());
            }

            // add the datarow for the overdue book for the email
            emailList[email].Add(row);
        }

        // Now, craft and send an email for each unique email address in the list
        foreach (string email in emailList.Keys)
        {
            // create a string builder to build up the body of the email
            StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
            body.Append("<html>");
            body.Append("<body>");

            // assume the first/last name will be the same for each row, so just get the
            // name information from the first row to build the opening line of the email
            DataRow firstRow = emailList[email][0];
            body.AppendFormat("<p>Dear {0} {1}:  The following book(s) are due:</p>", firstRow["FName"].ToString(), firstRow["LName"].ToString());
            body.Append("<ol>");

            // now just add a line item for each book
            foreach (DataRow row in emailList[email])
            {
                body.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", row["BookName"].ToString()); 
            }

            // close up your html tags
            body.Append("</ol>");
            body.Append("</body>");
            body.Append("</html>");

            // finally, send the email
            SendHtmlFormattedEmail(email, "Overdue Books", body.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void SendHtmlFormattedEmail(string recepientEmail, string subject, string body)
    {
        using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
        {
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"]);
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Body = body;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recepientEmail));
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
            smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]);
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
            NetworkCred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SendEmail();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have updated the question with a sample table. Tried your recommendation and it places all of the users in a single email. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.  I have updated the answer to send only one email per customer.

Comment: It's kool Jason: I am still getting two individual email content per-book. It's like the email body repeating it self for each book. My template is just a basic HTML. So instead of having multiple email body, I simply want to list, the due dates, and books due and date borrowed. *Please see update to question.

Comment: Ahh, I get it. Modified the answer again. Hopefully third times the charm. You would probably need to modify the section where the email body is created in order to put in any styling that you wanted. Or, you could alter your template to use different replace strings (like inserting the whole list of books as one replace block).

Comment: Thanks Jason. Its works! This was a persistent effort for an unusual approach. I will be asking other questions about GridViews but you have answered this one. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jason Young's example, but slightly modified to separate the emails for each different customer.

```
string lastCustId = "none";
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    if (!lastCustId.Equals("none") && !row["CustId"].ToString().Equals(lastCustId))
    {
        // Different customer's record, fire off the email to previous one
        SendHtmlFormattedEmail("Email", "Subject", body.ToString());
        lastCustId = row["CustId"].ToString();
    }
    // Build email for current customer
    CustFName = row["CustFName"].ToString();
    CustLName = row["CustLName"].ToString();
    CheckoutDate = row["CheckoutDate"].ToString();
    DueDate = row["DueDate"].ToString();
    BookName = row["BookName"].ToString();          
    body.AppendLine(PopulateBody(CustFName, CustLName, CheckoutDate, DueDate, BookName, template));
    // not sure what your template looks like, but this would be whatever
    // markup or text you would want separating your book details
    body.AppendLine("<br>");        
}
// Finally send email to the last customer in above loop
SendHtmlFormattedEmail("Email", "Subject", body.ToString());
```